# Weird radial gradient in Safari

Tags: css

Is there any way to get the radial gradient as beautiful as in Chrome?

Left is Chrome, right is Safari

[image]

Comment: This is called gradient banding. There is not much you can do about it. (don't quote me on this,) If you want consistent gradients across all browsers then use an optimized PNG image. Otherwise you just have to leave it to the browser's rendering engine.  Some will look nice, others...not so much.

Comment: I don't think you can make safari render the gradient better. Look up gradient banding. Maybe using an image rather than a gradient...